Hideflags 1.21?
How would I hideflags on an item dropped by loot table in minecraft 1.21? This seems to be done with a new component called "show_in_tooltip", but the generator I have been using (misode), does not have a place for this (though it could just be the generator).
In game I would do this:
give @p golden_sword[enchantments={levels:{"minecraft:sharpness":7},show_in_tooltip:false},enchantment_glint_override=true]

but I cant seem to find where to add this in the following loot table:
{
  "function": "minecraft:set_enchantments",
  "enchantments": {
    "minecraft:sharpness": 7
  }
}

